# How to refresh Listview in tab

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I want to refresh the listview when switching tabs in actionbar activity.

I tried

```
.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        Intent in = new Intent(Message.this,
            DataBaseServices.class);
        startService(in);//this will add the new entries in database
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

but it's not working. Also in the fragment class I called the `listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `listview.notiffyAll()` but this also not working.

Please help me.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. Just make sure your service actually saves data before notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Comment: can you post main activity and fragment codes?